# Joining 2 tables with different rows over a common column

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables as shown below I would want to join the tables so that it results in table as shown

TABLE 1

| Id | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ball |
| 2 | Bat |
| 3 | Gloves |
| 1 | Racket |
| 1 | Net |
| 2 | Tape |

TABLE 2

| Id | Price | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $1.99 | Black |
| 2 | $2.99 | Yellow |
| 3 | $3.99 | Green |

RESULT

| Id | Product Name | Price | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ball | $1.99 | Black |
| 2 | Bat | $2.99 | Yellow |
| 3 | Gloves | $3.99 | Green |
| 1 | Racket | $1.99 | Black |
| 1 | Net | $1.99 | Black |
| 2 | Tape | $2.99 | Yellow |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example given, it looks like you just need to join on `id` -

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING(id);
```